# Build error compiling Codename One iOS app after removing native interface code?

Tags: ios, codenameone

I followed the instructions on how to [add 3rd party libraries and implement native interfaces](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html) (all 3 parts, not just this first one). I am getting build errors that seem related to these interfaces, but after deleting the files, I am still getting the following error:

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/native_org_myapp_InterfaceTestPDFImplCodenameOne.o MyApp-src/native_org_myapp_InterfaceTestPDFImplCodenameOne.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

I have removed the `org` folders from each of the `native` folders. What can I do to get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You've cropped the error message so it isn't visible. You only show the portion that said failed but removed everything else including the compiler error message. We need the full error log to understand. Removing a package name or folder after you generate a native interface won't work as expected